# disable animation on screen rotation on Android

Tags: android, animation, rotation, screen

Is it possible to disable for an activity or application, the animation introduced in honeycomb when you rotate the device? I still want to detect rotation changes and rotate my activity but with no animation at all.

Comment: we cannot over come those animations.. because that's the default one and which will get changed for every devices..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable default animation from Portrait to Landscape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957772/disable-default-animation-from-portrait-to-landscape)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for developer's to remove the rotation animation for their application specifically. But user's do have the option to remove all window animations. 
But if it this is really necessary for your app, you could prompt users to toggle the "Remove Animations" accessibility setting or the "Window animation scale" developer setting, but other than that there is no way to get rid of these animation.